# How to get file image source from file path in xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How to get file image source from file path in Xamarin Forms here i have stored a folder locally by using dependency services.

```cs
_fileHelper = _fileHelper ?? DependencyService.Get<IFileHelper>();

 profiletap.Tapped += async (s, e) =>
{
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();
    if (file == null)
    return;
    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    profile.Source = im;

    imageName = "SomeUniqueFileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss-tt");
    filePath  = _fileHelper.CopyFile(file.Path, imageName);

    im = ImageSource.FromFile(filePath)
}
```

i want to upload image from media picker permanently so that i can not loose image once uploaded public string CopyFile(string sourceFile, string destinationFilename, bool overwrite = true)
        {

```
        if (!File.Exists(sourceFile)) { return string.Empty; }
        string fullFileLocation = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) );
        File.Copy(sourceFile, fullFileLocation, overwrite);
        return fullFileLocation;
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do some more? What have you tried? And where do you fail? Also the code you posted doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: i want to upload image from media picker permanently so that i can not loose image once uploaded....here is my android code

Answer (score 1):

```
im = ImageSource.FromStream(()=> file.GetStream());
```